# Are PWA can be called as Mobile development App?

Tags: native, hybrid-mobile-app, progressive-web-apps, mobile-application

Can we call PWAs a part/type of Mobile development app just like Native and Hybrid Mobile Apps?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want because the name of it doesn't change what it actually is or is not.

Answer (score 0):

It's arguable. I would say it is much closer to Web Development than Mobile.